# Inner join sql пояснить запрос

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, inner-join

Всем привет!
Есть пример запроса:

```
SELECT t.name,
       SUM(i.quantity),
       pt.playlist_id,
       p.name
FROM track AS t
INNER JOIN invoice_line AS i ON t.track_id=i.track_id
INNER JOIN playlist_track AS pt ON t.track_id=pt.track_id
INNER JOIN playlist AS p ON pt.playlist_id = p.playlist_id
GROUP BY t.name, pt.playlist_id, p.name
LIMIT 20;
```

Условия задачи : Ид плейлиста указан в итоговой таблице. Но плейлисты непонятно. Информацию можно взять в четвёртой таблице — playlist. В таблице есть playlist_id с идентификатором плейлиста и поле name — с названием. Добавьте в итоговую таблицу поле name.
Данные без совпадения не должны попасть в таблицы, ограничить вывод первыми 20 записями.

Результат выведет name, sum, playlist_id
Правильно понимаю, что в селект мы выбираем 3 поля и потом объединяем по Ид трека? Группируем.
А название треков не должны выгрузится?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, вы выводите два столбца с одинаковым именем name. Поэтому вместо четырёх видите только три столбца. Задайте им алиасы.

```
SELECT t.name as track_name,
       SUM(i.quantity),
       pt.playlist_id,
       p.name as playlist_name
...
```